# "$file" variable nor working with exec command

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to set a shortcut to open my current file using an external program (in my case, Visual Studio).

I thought I could use the `$file` variable, available in the build system. So it I write:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+o"], "command": "exec", "args": {"shell_cmd": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe\" $file"} }
```

I get in the Sublime console prompt:

```
Running "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" $file
```

As you can see, the `$file` variable isn't expanded to the pull path of the open file. Does anyone know what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for (but for OS X) was to use it like this:

```
  { "keys": ["super+shift+option+o"], "command": "exec", "args": {"cmd": ["open", "-a", "ForkLift", ""]}}
```